# Como elimino este cuadro de dialogo al recibir notificaciones dentro de App

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-notifications, onesignal

Buenas gente estoy como loco intentando quitar un cuadro de dialogo que se genera automáticamente al recibir una notificación en mi app desde onesignal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A mi parecer es un AlerDialog que no tengo idea de como se crea. Revise la documentación de onesignal y no encuentro nada. Lo mas raro es que si estoy dentro de la app visualizando el contenido y me llega una notificación la app se sale y pasa a segundo plano y desde el multitareas luego veo que llega ese mensaje.

El botón OK no se de donde sale ya que no es un dialogo creado por mi. 
Para mi lo ideal seria que la notificación solo llegue en la bandeja de android y que si estoy dentro de la App no cambie mi actividad o la resetee como la esta haciendo. Adjunto mi código

```js
   
   
public class App extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setApiKey("<VAL>").
                setApplicationId("<VAL>").build());

        //OneSignal Push
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(getString(R.string.onesignal_app_id)))
            OneSignal.init(this, getString(R.string.onesignal_google_project_number), getString(R.string.onesignal_app_id), new NotificationHandler());

    }

    // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it or one is received while the app is running.
    private class NotificationHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
        // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.
        @Override
        public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
            try {
                JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;

                String webViewUrl = (data != null) ? data.optString("url", null) : null;
                String browserUrl = result.notification.payload.launchURL;

                if (webViewUrl != null || browserUrl != null) {
                    if (webViewUrl != null){
                        HolderActivity.startWebViewActivity(App.this, webViewUrl, false, false, null, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    } else {
                        HolderActivity.startWebViewActivity(App.this, browserUrl, true, false, null, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    }
                } else if (!result.notification.isAppInFocus) {
                    Intent mainIntent;
                    mainIntent = new Intent(App.this, MainActivity.class);
                    mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                }

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Alguna idea de que pueda generar este dialogo? Ya busque en todo mi codigo y no lo encuentro me imagino que se genera desde la Api

Comment: ¿Te refieres al "PRUEBA NUEVA ESPAÑOL"? ¿Cómo va a crear la API automáticamente un cuadro de diálogo con un texto indicando que es una prueba, y menos en español? Eso está hardcordeado en alguna parte de tu código, no tiene sentido otra cosa.

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando el SDK de [OneSignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup), el AlertDialog se va a mostrar cuando una notificación es recibida.

Si no deseas ver el alertDialog al recibir una notificación, simplemente no inicialices [OneSignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup):

```
    //OneSignal Push
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(getString(R.string.onesignal_app_id)))
        //Inicializacion.
        //OneSignal.init(this, getString(R.string.onesignal_google_project_number), getString(R.string.onesignal_app_id), new NotificationHandler());
```